# Phased Array Toolbox and directivity of IsotopicAntennaElement

Tags: matlab, physics, telecommunication

Cannot you explain how and in what units `directivity` is calculated in MATLAB Phased Array Toolbox?

I run their [simple example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/phased.isotropicantennaelement.directivity.html) with `IsotropicAntennaElement`.

```
myAnt = phased.IsotropicAntennaElement();
ang = [-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
freq = 1e9;

d = directivity(myAnt,freq,ang)
```

It gives me this:

```
d =

   1.0e-03 *

    0.1102
    0.1102
    0.1102
    0.1102
    0.1102
    0.1102
    0.1102
```

MATLAB manual tells that directivity is the ratio of the intensity in given direction and the intensity of an isotropic antenna of the same power.

But what's the hell, **why it does not give 0 dB on the directivity of an isotopic antenna itself?**

Does it mean that an isotropic antenna radiates less, than an isotropic antenna? Or how should I understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in [**dBi units**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Antenna_measurements), as stated in the the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/phased.ula.directivity.html):

> `directivity`  Compute element directivity
>
> `D = directivity(H,FREQ,ANGLE)` computes the directivity (in dBi)
>       of the element for the directions specified in `ANGLE` (in
>       degrees) and frequencies specified in `FREQ` (in Hz).

So it should be `0` for an isotropic antenna. You are getting `0.0001102`, which is acceptably close to `0`.